# Failed to save options error in Liquid XML Studio

Tags: liquid-xml

When saving the settings using Tools->Options you may see an error:
"Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically due to your anti-virus program or security permissions.

Specifically, we have seen error when McAfee Real-Time Scanner is active.

To resolve this issue, add the following file to the Excluded File list in the Anti-virus software:

> %APPDATA%\Liquid Technologies Ltd\Liquid XML Studio
>   2015\UserSettings.xml

But also check that your account has read/write access to the containing folder

> %APPDATA%\Liquid Technologies Ltd